# How to know the missing items from Spring Data JPA's findAllById method in an efficient way?

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Consider this code snippet below:

```
List<String> usersList = Arrays.asList("john", "jack", "jill", "xxxx", "yyyy");
List<User> userEntities = userRepo.findAllById(usersList);
```

`User` class is a simple Entity object annotated with `@Entity` and has an `@Id` field which is of String datatype.

Assume that in db I have rows corresponding to `"john", "jack" and "jill"`. Even though I passed 5 items in `usersList`(along with `"xxxx" and "yyyy"`), `findAllById` method would **only** return **3 items/entities** corresponding to `"john","jack",and "jill"`.

Now after the call to `findAllById` method, what's the best, easy and efficient(better than O(n^2) perhaps) way to find out the missing items which `findAllById` method did not return?(In this case, it would be `"xxxx" and "yyyy"`).

Comment: You mean which items from you list were not found in the database?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have to let the consumer of my service know that some of the userIds which they requested were not found in database(and of course I need to specifically tell them which userIds are not present in db). I can run two nested for loops over both lists and find the ones that are not in userEntities list, but I feel like this is inefficient. Is there a spring method which tells me the ids which it was not able to find when querying the db or is there a better way to do this altogether(better than O(n^2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Java Sets

You could use a set as the source of filtering:

```java
Set<String> usersSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("john", "jack", "jill", "xxxx", "yyyy"));
```

And now you could create a predicate to filter those not present:

```java
Set<String> foundIds = userRepo.findAllById(usersSet)
     .stream()
     .map(User::getId)
     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I assume the filter should be O(n) to go over the entire results.

Or you could change your repository to return a set of users ideally using a form of `distinct` clause:

```java
Set<String> foundIds = userRepo.findDistinctById(usersSet)
       .stream()
       .map(User::getId)
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());;
```

And then you can just apply a set operator:

```
usersSet.removeAll(foundIds);
```

And now `usersSet` contains the users not found in your result.

And a set has a O(1) complexity to find an item. So, I assume this should be O(sizeOf(userSet)) to remove them all.

Alternatively, you could iterate over the `foundIds` and gradually remove items from the `userSet`. Then you could short-circuit the loop algorithm in the event you realize that there are no more `userSet` items to remove (i.e. the set is empty).

#### Filtering Directly from Database

Now to avoid all this, you can probably define a native query and run it in your JPA repository to retrieve only users from your list which didn't exist in the database. The query would be somewhat as follows that I did in PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH my_users AS(
   SELECT 'john' AS id UNION SELECT 'jack' UNION SELECT 'jill'
) 
SELECT id FROM my_users mu 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.id = mu.id);
```

#### Spring Data: JDBC Example

Since the query is dynamic (i.e. the filtering set could be of different sizes every time), we need to build the query dynamically. And I don't believe JPA has a way to do this, but a native query might do the trick.

You could either pack a `JdbcTemplate` query directly into your repository or use JPA native queries manually.

```java
@Repository
public class UserRepository {
    
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public UserRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;}

    public Set<String> getUserIdNotFound(Set<String> userIds) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        for(String userId : userIds) {
            if(sql.length() > 0) {
                sql.append(" UNION ");
            }
            sql.append("SELECT ? AS id");
        }

        String query = String.format("WITH my_users AS (%sql)", sql) +
                "SELECT id FROM my_users mu WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.id = mu.id)";

        List<String> myUsers = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, userIds.toArray(), String.class);

        return new HashSet<>(myUsers);
    }

}
```

Then we just do:

```java
Set<String> usersIds = Set.of("john", "jack", "jill", "xxxx", "yyyy");
Set<String> notFoundIds = userRepo.getUserIdNotFound(usersIds);
```

There is probably a way to do it with JPA native queries. Let me see if I can do one of those and put it in the answer later on.

Comment: Nice, didn't think of sets. Just curious, Would this faster than running two nested for loops or doing what Aleksey Kurkov above suggested? Not sure what the time complexity of removeAll method is.

Comment: @theprogrammer Added an example of how to query directly from the database in case that helps. If possible I will add how to run this in Spring Data.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own algorithm that finds missing users. For example:

```
List<String> missing = new ArrayList<>(usersList);

        for (User user : userEntities){
            String userId = user.getId();
            missing.remove(userId);
        }
```

In the result you will have a list of user-ids that are missing:

`"xxxx"` and `"yyyy"`

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of doing this as well. But I believe ArrayList's remove method has O(n) time complexity and therefore this would yield O(n^2) time complexity. I was wondering if Spring Data Jpa could return it during findAllBy method call itself in an efficient way?

Comment: Don't know about Spring method complexity... But what if we switch to LinkedList? It has better performance in removing items. `List<String> missing = new LinkedList<>(usersList);`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a method to your repo:

`findByIdNotIn(Collection<String> ids)` and Spring will make the query:

See here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Note (from the docs):

> > In and NotIn also take any subclass of Collection as aparameter as well as arrays or varargs.

Comment: So you mean that I should call this method after I've called findAllById method? If yes, then this is very inefficient no? Why make a db call, when I can simply find the intersection between java objects that I already have(usersList and userEntities from my example)? Intersection of java objects(which are already loaded into memory) would be much faster than making another db call I believe